# Recurrent Neural Network in Pybrain

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, pybrain

I am following the [recurrent network tutorial in the Pybrain documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html#using-recurrent-networks) and I do not know how to build the network so that it looks back more than one time step. Any help is appreciated.

```
from pybrain.structure import RecurrentNetwork
n = RecurrentNetwork()
n.addInputModule(LinearLayer(2, name='in'))
n.addModule(SigmoidLayer(3, name='hidden'))
n.addOutputModule(LinearLayer(1, name='out'))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['in'], n['hidden'], name='c1'))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['hidden'], n['out'], name='c2'))
n.addRecurrentConnection(FullConnection(n['hidden'], n['hidden'], name='c3'))
```

Just adding `n.addRecurrentConnection(FullConnection(n['hidden'], n['hidden'], name='c4'))` will not do the trick, correct?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way unless you implement your own recurrent connection to support multiple time steps.